# how to invoke callback tcl procedure from c

Tags: c, callback, tcl, swig

I am working on Tcl. and using swig to extend the TCL command with C.
Now, I want the extended command in C to callback the tcl procedure. 
But I have no idea of it.

Please help me.

First, I implement a dispatcher function in swig,which call mrecv.
And in my tcl script. I call the mrecv to receive message. so, when a message arrived, i hope tcl can be notified by mrecv. that why I need find a way that invoke the callback tcl procedure from c.

And my codes is breifly is

```
W16 mrecv(int timeout) {
    W16 res;
    Msg_t *msg = NULL;
    APP_EVENT_T eventList[255];
    int listLength = 255;

    while (1) {
        readAgain = 0;
        msg = malloc(sizeof(Msg_t));  
        if (!msg) {
            return RETURN_ERR;
        }
        memset(msg, 0, sizeof(Msg_t));
        res = MsgRecvEvent(msg, eventList, &listLength, timeout);
        if (res == RETURN_OK) {
            msgDispatcher(msg);
        }
        free(msg);

    }                               
    return res;
 }
 void msgDispather(void *msg) {
     /*notify tcl*/
 }
```

and in my tcl script. I call mrecv command.
tcl script:

```
 res [ mrecv 3000 ]
```

I need to know how to notify tcl.

below is my test demo.

```
int testCallback (char * str) {
    Tcl_Interp *interp;
    interp=Tcl_CreateInterp();
    Tcl_Eval(interp,str);
    return 0;
}
```

testCallback() is the extended cmd which will be called by tcl. str is the procedure name in tcl.

Comment: Can you make your question more specific? This is a bit too broad for StackOverflow at the moment. What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: You _really_ don't want to create interpreters very often (they're heavyweight) and they're not garbage-collected. You also probably want to use an existing one so that users can set things up before you have to actually process the callback…

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at the Tcl_Eval family of functions which execute Tcl scripts.  These take as there first parameter a pointer to the Tcl interpreter where the script is to run; and a pointer is the current interpeter is one of the parameters passed into the C function that SWIG will generate.

At present your testCallback() function creates a new Tcl_Interp and evaluates the command in that new interp.  What you want to do is evaluate the command in the same Tcl_Interp that you ran the `mrecv 3000` from.

In order to do this you have to convince SWIG to pass the Tcl_Interp into your mrecv function, and I think you can do this using the SWIG typemap functionality.

If you create a new typemap:

```
%typemap(in,numinputs=0) Tcl_Interp *interp {  
    $1 = interp;
}
```

and change the signature of your function to:

```
W16 mrecv(int timeout, Tcl_Interp *interp)
```

then SWIG **should** automatically pass the Tcl_Interp into your mrecv function without you needing to change the Tcl code.

See [here](https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Lib/tcl/tclinterp.i) for the source of the typemap and [here](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Typemaps_nn26) for more information on the in typemap that makes this possible.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have detailed my question.

Comment: @user3350310 I think the above now answers your question.

Comment: In particular, `Tcl_Eval` is for running a script and `Tcl_EvalObjv` is for calling a single command with literal arguments.